Could water have caused a on and off bulge in kitchen ceiling?
I recently noticed an on and off bulge in my kitchen ceiling that seems to appear every couple of days before becoming flat again. When it is flat, there are still some dark marks (though not brown) in the area, and when you look at it from the side it looks almost shiny.
We recently had our bathroom redone upstairs so are wondering if it could be linked to a leak/water damage of any kind? The place that did our bathroom has checked out of the outlets (if that’s the right word) under the floorboards upstairs for any evidence, but not all of them have been checked. We also had our ceiling slightly lowered a few months ago, so there are fresh boards up there and it was completely flat previously, but the old ceiling is still there. The guy who did the job has said that the width of the timbers that he used before boarding over would be about the same as the bulge in the ceiling if water is following one of them. For what it’s worth, the area is above our Aga which runs warm throughout the day.
Long story short, just looking to find out what’s causing this on and off bulge and if we have a water problem that we need to worry about. Any help or insight would be massively appreciated. Thanks!




That has the typical look of water intrusion.   From what, is unknown, but a good guess would be the bathroom above.

Does the timing it shows, match timing of doing something in the bathroom?  Like taking a shower every two days.

Thank you for the replies. The bathroom is in the area above the kitchen, though the timing of it appearing doesn't seem to immediately match bathroom activity, e.g. after having a bath/shower or using the toilet or sink (maybe due to the old ceiling?). Can't really explain why it then disappears either, our only guess was heat from the Aga!

It can take time for water to flow, and if the drywall if dry, it can take further time to show up on the other side.

A tiny leak from the drain pipe plus the heat might explain it.  A small inspection camera would be helpful.  Access to the plumbing either from above or below will probably be in your future.

You might make a narrow cut at the lowest part of the bulge and then monitor whether any water drops form the next time the bulging occurs. Or touch it now and later to check for a soft, cold, or wet feeling. An electronic moisture probe is a diagnostic tool that might be useful.

Part of the issue might be weight of bathtub, when full of water... though that would not discolor ceiling.
